# jQuery UI Datapicker and dates from DB (asp.net)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

Is there way to load dates from DB and paste it do datepicker so that that date from DB would have diferent class (colour) on that date in datepicker, or is there other calendar that can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Script Below reads date value from Database and passes them as array to calendar `[<%=sBlockedDates%>]`

Actual Array example

```
var holiDays = [[2012,25, 12, 'Christmas'],[2012,7, 7, 'WEEKEND Event'],[2012,7, 13, 'Some Holiday'],[2012,7, 14, 'Festival']];
```

**Script for UI Calendar**

Besides this script below disable previous dates and dates greater than +90 Days & also blocks date passed as array. You can alter the script to according to your logic.

```
function BindEvents()
{
//Script for Calendar
        var holiDays = [<%=sBlockedDates%>];
        $(function () {
            $("#<%=txtBookingDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: "-0d",
                maxDate: "+90d",
                firstDay: 0,
                beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates
            });

            function noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates(date) {
                //var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                return setHoliDays(date);
            }

            // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
            function setHoliDays(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                if (day == 5 || day ==6) return [false, 'CalWeekEnd', ];

                for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
                    if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
                        && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
                        && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
                        return [false, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
                    }
                }
                return [true, ''];
            }
        });
}

BindEvents();
```

Comment: Cool tnx this will help. I was considering dhtmlxcalendar but this will work great

Comment: where is to place it `[<%=sBlockedDates%>];`? can you show me how to declare that's? @Learning

Comment: can you help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501929/binding-of-jquery-ui-datepicker-from-db-sql-server-asp-net-webforms

Comment: i think it's similar with this question

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a way like : fetch dates from database and store them in an array and after that using the below function to highlight them using your special css. May be its helpful for you.

$(function() {

```
  //Dates are Year, months-1 (Jan is 0,...,Dec is 11), day
    var dates = [new Date(2011, 10, 15), new Date(2011, 10, 10)];
    function highlightDays(date) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            if (
            (dates[i].getDate() == date.getDate()) && 
            (dates[i].getMonth() == date.getMonth()) && 
            (dates[i].getFullYear() == date.getFullYear())
            ) {
                return [true,'highlight','Highlighted day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, '','All other dates'];
    }
    function pickUpDate(dateText, inst) {
        var theURL = "#"+dateText;
        //window.location = theURL; //this for opening in the same window
        window.open(theURL); //this for opening in the new window
    }
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: highlightDays,
        onSelect: pickUpDate
    });
});
```