# Binding of jquery ui datepicker from db sql server asp net webforms

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I want to set holiday in jquery datepicker and I've been try this code from [jQuery UI Datapicker and dates from DB (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11291804/jquery-ui-datapicker-and-dates-from-db-asp-net)

```
function BindEvents() {
            //Script for Calendar
            var holiDays = [[2020, 25, 12, 'Christmas'], [2020, 7, 7, 'WEEKEND Event'], [2020, 7, 13, 'Some Holiday'], [2012, 7, 14, 'Festival']];
            $(function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates
            });

            function noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates(date) {
                //var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                return setHoliDays(date);
            }

            // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
            function setHoliDays(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                if (day == 5 || day == 6) return [false, 'CalWeekEnd',];

                for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
                    if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
                        && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
                        && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
                        return [false, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
                    }
                }
                return [true, ''];
            }
        });
        }

        BindEvents();
```

and i use textbox to show jquery datepicker

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="datepicker"  />
             <br />
```

how to call `var holidays` from database in sql server?

and i've been try this too https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/740756/Binding-of-Calendar-Controls-from-Database but it use calendar control not jquery datepicker

Answer (score 0):

If there is an issue of setting an data from database to this variable "holiDays". Then you have to use jquery ajax function to fetch data from database by WebMethod in code side.

Example : Like below. So this function will fetch data from database and show result in success function. As mention in code "console.log(result)" there you have to loop your data and push that data to array to get similar result as you want.

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetCustomers",
                    data: '',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                     console.log(result);
                     },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                     },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                    });
```